# inconsistent display of pdf in browser using php

Tags: php, pdf

hi im trying to display pdf in browser and i used this code to do the work

```
<?php

            $pdf = 'uploads/docs/' . $list->filename;
            // dd($pdf);
            header('Content-type: application/pdf');
            header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $pdf . '"');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($pdf));
            header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

            @readfile($pdf);
            exit;
        ?>
```

it is working but i have one problem sometimes it does not display 1-2 pages pdf files any idea what i am doing wrong? any advices? thanks

Comment: I'm surprised it's not downloading it with those headers.  General the content-type is enough for display.  Typically less is more when it comes to headers.

Comment: hi @ArtisiticPhoenix actually i just replicated other peoples idea regarding this function hehe. anyways removing other header except content-type did the trick. Thanks! :)